Linking AR Scenes to UI Developed with Unity AR Toolkit
We've been working on developing an AR app and we used Unity AR Toolkit to develop our UI, and we've hit a roadblock. We've successfully created our AR scenes, but now we're struggling to link it to our UI, which we've built it using Unity UI Toolkit/Builder.
Our main challenge is understanding how to establish this connection between our AR scenes and the UI elements. We're looking for guidance on how to properly reroute or link the AR scenes to our UI controls.
Here are some specific questions we have:

How can we use C# scripting to handle UI interactions and control AR scene switching?

Are there any specific functions or methods in Unity AR Toolkit that we should be using for this purpose?

What is the best approach for integrating AR scenes with UI elements in Unity?


Any advice, code snippets, or resources would be greatly appreciated. We're eager to overcome this hurdle and continue building our AR project.
Thank you in advance for your help!
